# Using fnmatch with a char Pointer

Tags: c, wildcard

The array `options` contains elements of this form: "-option=value".

The argument `needed_option` contains for example "option"

```
char *function(char *options[], char *needed_option){
    for(//go over all possible options){
       if(fnmatch("-???=*", options[i], 0) == 0){ //<--- look here
           char *ret = extract_value_from_option(); 
           return ret;
        }
    }

}
```

Question: Is there a way to genericly replace the "`???`" with the function - argument `needed_option` like its done in `printf()` where a `char *` can be included by using the `%s` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prepare it with [sprintf()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/sprintf/)

```
  char current[256];
  sprintf(current, "-%s=*", needed_option);
  //...
  if(fnmatch(current, options[i], 0) == 0){ //...
```

Comment: great, it performs just like requested although the man 3 sprintf is a pain in the ass